# Matching polymorphic data in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Lets say we have a data defined named Stuff:

```
data Stuff = Stuff1 Int
           | Stuff2 Int
           | Stuff3 Int

sumStuff :: [Stuff] -> Int
sumStuff [] = 0
sumStuff ((Stuff1 x):xs) = x + sumStuff xs
sumStuff ((Stuff2 x):xs) = x + sumStuff xs
sumStuff ((Stuff3 x):xs) = x + sumStuff xs

sumStuff' :: [Stuff] -> Int
sumStuff' [] = 0
sumStuff' ((_ x):xs) = x+sumStuff xs
```

How can I match all types without pattern matching like in the wrong definition in sumStuff' ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could take a different approach with your data structure if it's as homogenous as your example:

```
data StuffType = Stuff1 | Stuff2 | Stuff3 deriving (Eq, Show)

data Stuff a = Stuff StuffType a deriving (Eq, Show)

extractStuff :: Stuff a -> a
extractStuff (Stuff _ a) = a

sumStuff :: Stuff Int -> Int
sumStuff = sum . map extractStuff
```

I've even made the value contained in `Stuff` polymorphic, in case you wanted to store `String`s or even more `Stuff`s in them.  This approach allows you to pattern match on the `StuffType` when you need it, but stick with a single pattern case when you don't.

You could also define this using records to avoid pattern matches altogether:

```
data Stuff a = Stuff { stuffType :: StuffType, extractStuff :: a } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and `sumStuff` would have the same definition, but you wouldn't need to define `extractStuff` manually.

Comment: This is lazier than the other answers. If every `Stuff` holds `exactStuff`, you don't need to determine if it's `Stuff1`, `Stuff2`, or `Stuff3` before using the `exactStuff`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [Lenses](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/blob/master/README.markdown) They allow you to look into data types and view or change the contained value(s), and in cases such as this, they can simplify pattern matching. [This](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial) Is a good place to start learning about them.

writing this with Lenses could look something like:

```
data Stuff = Stuff1 { _stuff :: Int } |
             Stuff2 { _stuff :: Int } |
             Stuff3 { _stuff :: Int }
makeLenses ''Stuff

sumStuff []     = 0
sumStuff (x:xs) = x ^. stuff + sumStuff xs
```

In this case Lenses might be overkill since you could just use record syntax. i.e.

```
data Stuff = Stuff1 {stuff :: Int } |
             Stuff2 {stuff :: Int } |
             Stuff3 {stuff :: Int }

sumStuff []     = 0
sumStuff (x:xs) = stuff x + sumStuff xs
```

or `sumStuff = foldr ((+) . stuff) 0`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't. The best you can do is to write something like this:

```
toInt :: Stuff -> Int
toInt (Stuff1 x) = x
toInt (Stuff2 x) = x
toInt (Stuff3 x) = x

sumStuff :: [Stuff] -> Int
sumStuff [] = 0
sumStuff (x:xs) = toInt x + sumStuff xs
```

Essentially you're hiding the pattern matching behind the `toInt` function.